# How to add animation to a StreamBuilder that is working as a router based on firebase AuthState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-animation

In my `main.dart` I'm returning `Router()` widget as my `home`. In `Router.dart` I basically have `StreamBuilder` which takes `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` as `stream` and returns which widget to show based on user's `AuthState`. If the `connectionState` is `waiting` I return `Splash` as a custom Splash Screen. if `snapshot.hasData` I return `Home` widget, if it doesn't I return `Login` widget.

Now my problem is the whole routing is working fine, but I need to animate the transitions. let's say from `Splash` to any widget transition `Splash` will just fade out. From `Login` to `Home` transition `Login` will slide to left. From `Home` to `Login` transition `Login` will slide from left. How can I animate these changes?

These are my files:

**main.dart**

```
import 'router.dart';
void main() => runApp(Main());

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
       //Theme
      ),
      home: Router(),
    );
  }
}
```

**router.dart**

```
import 'login.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class Router extends StatefulWidget {
  _RouterState createState() => _RouterState();
}

class _RouterState extends State<Router> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Splash();
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Home();
          }
          return Login();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Splash"
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Please comment if each widget files are needed. I haven't uploaded them cause they are large and include some secrets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met that same problem. I recommend you to use stream.listen in didChangeDependencies() instead StreamBuilder. And you use Navigator.pushReplacement() with transition animation depending on Auth state.

example code:

```
class Router extends StatefulWidget {
  _RouterState createState() => _RouterState();
}

class _RouterState extends State<Router> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        _next(context, Home());
      }
      _next(context, Login());
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  _next(BuildContext context, Widget nextPage) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return nextPage;
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween<double>(
              begin: 0.0,
              end: 1.0,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Splash();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HeavenOSK it works! But instead I'm using a solution derived from your older answer.I'm listening to `onAuthStateChanged` in `initState` and routing with named routes based on that. But It's not done yet. Just like a real app I want users to NOT be able to go back to login screen after they've logged in or go back to main page after they logged out but I can't. And I'm wanting `router` to handle everything about routing based on auth state just to centralise behaviours and aesthetics.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want as you say, I recommend you to use `pushAndRemoveUntil` method depends on the situations. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html

Comment: Again thank you but is there a way to use `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` because I'm using named routes now?

Comment: I think both methods are almost same. So you can also use `pushNamedAndRemoveUnitl`.

Answer (score 3):

To perform an animation to transition between widget in a streambuilder, it's easy, simply use a widget called [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: _getMainWidget(snapshot, context),
    );
  },
);
}
```

Here we use an [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) to animate a transition when the child of the AnimatedSwitcher change's, the default animation is a fade animation, but you could add your custom animation by passing the widget a [TransitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionBuilder.html) as an argument